# Adding different length columns to cell array in a loop and labeling them

Tags: matlab, structure, cell-array

I have a for loop where I extract some data from .csv files:

```
    % Startup
clearvars;

stress_folder = uigetdir(path,'Select STRESS folder');
strain_folder = uigetdir(path,'Select STRAIN folder');

prompt = {'Plot name:','x label (strain):','y label (stress):','Name of STRAIN values:','Name of STRESS values:'};
dlg_title = 'Input';
num_lines = 1;
defaultans = {'Title','x label','y label','Surface component 1.avg(epsY) [True strain]','Stress'};
answer = inputdlg(prompt,dlg_title,num_lines,defaultans);

filePattern = sprintf('%s/*.csv', stress_folder);
stress_file_list = dir(filePattern);
filePattern = sprintf('%s/*.csv', strain_folder);
strain_file_list = dir(filePattern);

name_plot = answer{1};
x_label = answer{2};
y_label = answer{3};
strain_col = answer{4};
stress_col = answer{5};

des_cols = {stress_col,strain_col};
smallest_n = 100000;
avg_stress_values = [];
avg_strain_values = [];
ii=0;

% Determine smallest set of data
for file = stress_file_list'

    M = xlsread(fullfile(stress_folder,file.name));
    [row,col] = size(M);
    if smallest_n > row
        smallest_n = row;
    end
end
for file = strain_file_list'
    M=xlsread(fullfile(strain_folder,file.name));
    [row,col]=size(M);
    if smallest_n > row
        smallest_n = row;
    end
end

% Extract columns
for file = stress_file_list'
    ii = ii + 1;
    [n,s,r] = xlsread(fullfile(stress_folder,file.name));
    [row, col] = find(strcmpi(s,stress_col));
    stress_values = n(1:end,col);
    avg_stress_values(:,ii)=stress_values(1:smallest_n);
    % place for code to store stress_values in a cell array or structure array at column index ii
end
ii=0;
for file = strain_file_list'
    ii = ii + 1;
    [n,s,r] = xlsread(fullfile(strain_folder,file.name));
    [row, col] = find(strcmpi(s,strain_col));
    strain_values = n(1:end,col);
    avg_strain_values(:,ii)=strain_values(1:smallest_n);
    % place for code to store strain_values in a cell array or structure array at column index ii
end

% Plot the averages
ylabel({y_label});
xlabel({x_label});
title({name_plot});
colormap(gray);
hold off;

avg_strain_values = mean(avg_strain_values,2);
avg_stress_values = mean(avg_stress_values,2);
plot(avg_strain_values,avg_stress_values);
set(gca,'FontSize',20);
ylabel({y_label});
xlabel({x_label});
title({name_plot});
```

In the extract columns section I would like to store all the data in a...thing, for lack of a better word, and then plot it. From what I understand I could either use structure arrays or cell arrays but I'm not sure which one would suit my purpose better. I'm not sure whether it would be better to create two cell arrays, one for stress one for strain, or a structure array with fields for stress and strain and sub-fields for each set of data.

A problem is that the length of the data columns extracted from the .csv files are not the same length so appending columns at every iteration is difficult. I could make a loop at the beginning which finds the biggest column size and then create the structure/cell array of that size if that helps.

Comment: This shows no sample code data to illustrate what you are trying to do. The question is very vague, so please be as explicit as you can.

Comment: My apologies, let me rephrase my question. I have a loop that extracts columns of data of differing lengths from .csv files. I would like to store them in either a structure array or a cell array because then I would like to plot them. Which data type is easier to use for large amounts of numerical data that then needs to get plotted?

Comment: Arrays, just like everything else.

Comment: Yes but which type of array? A normal one? A cell array? A structure array? How do I deal with the fact that the data extracted from the .csv files is of different sizes?